# Installed XStream Dependency Not Recognized as a Class (Java 17 + Intellij)

Tags: xml, intellij-idea, xstream, missing-features

I am looking into marshalling and unmarshalling xml data for a program design, and I've correctly installed XStream into my Maven dependency.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9NeQQ.png

The library is not missing from my project...

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tGC12.png

But when I go to initialize the class, XStream is not available in any import.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZCRm.png

Is this an issue with my pom.xml dependencies or plugins? Am I supposed to add a custom file to my main package, resource package, or anywhere else?

My project is a JavaFx project with JDK 17.0.1 and default Maven dependencies on creation. Thanks for anyone's help in advance!

Comment: Is XStream shown as a module dependency in "Project Structure | Module - Dependencies"?

Comment: Yes. It is in the pom.xml and when I reloaded Maven, it installed as a dependency.

Comment: Is it possible to share sample project demonstrating the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I actually found the answer by messing around with dependency injection.

Though there is still an overall error, this gave me access to the dependency class for XML binding.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XKLOM.png

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code. Paste the text here.